# eliminar palabras repetidas en 2 celdas diferentes

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Me he quedado atascado al hacer una hoja en la que quiero eliminar una serie de palabras que tengo en 2 celdas diferentes.

```
En la celda A1 tendría GLUTEN, SOJA,
En la celda A2 tendría SOJA, GLUTEN, SESAMO, PESCADO,
```

Me gustaría obtener en una 3ª celda, `A3: SÉSAMO, PESCADO,` sólamente. Es decir, eliminar las palabras, delimitadas por comas y espacios, que se repitan en ambas celdas (en el ejemplo "SOJA", "GLUTEN") aunque estén desordenadas dentro de la cadena de texto.

La fórmula que he intentado utilizar es:

```
= TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2;A1;""))
```

Pero obtengo `SOJA`, `GLUTEN`, `SESAMO`, `PESCADO`. Como no tengo las palabras "GLUTEN" y "SOJA" en el mismo orden, al hacer la fórmula, me deja todas las palabras, sin eliminar ninguna de las que se repiten.

¿Me podría alguien sugerir alguna fórmula o macro efectiva para conseguir eliminar las palabras, aunque estén desordenadas dentro de una cadena de texto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear esta funcion en un módulo y luego llamarla en A3

```
=EliminarDuplicados(A1:A2;",")
```

La función es la siguiente (está comentada cada parte):

```
Function EliminarDuplicados(celdas As Range, Optional delim As String = ",") As String
    Dim x
    Dim txt As String
    txt = ""

    'Cadena que contiene el texto de todas las celdas
    For Each c In celdas.Cells
        txt = txt + c.Value + delim + " "
    Next

    'Objeto tipo matriz con elementos clave - valor
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

        'Se obtiene cada palabra dividiendo la cadena txt por el delimitador pasado como parámetro
        For Each x In Split(txt, delim)
            If Trim(x) <> "" Then
                'Si la palabra no existe se añade a la matriz
                If Not .Exists(Trim(x)) Then
                    .Add Trim(x), Nothing
                'Si ya exite se elimina esa palabra de la matriz
                Else
                  .Remove Trim(x)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then EliminarDuplicados = Join(.keys, delim + " ")
    End With
End Function
```

**Te muestro el ejemplo en imagen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, aunque hay algo que falla. Al guardar el módulo y aplicar la fórmula sobre la celda A3, obtengo "GLUTEN, SOJA, SOJA, GLUTEN, SÉSAMO, PESCADO". en lugar de "SÉSAMO, PESCADO" que era lo que quería conseguir. Es decir, me añade las palabras de la celda A1 a las que ya existen en la celda A2 y no me elimina las duplicadas.

Comment: @Ruy hola, he cambiado la formula de A3, tenia una "coma" después del rango. Utiliza ';' . He probado en una excel y me funciona bien.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, DevCodeG, Funciona. Sólo una pregunta más, si tuviera las celdas con las cadenas de texto en A1 y en A3  y quisiera hacer la fórmula en A4, pero en A2 tuviera una celda que quiero excluir con otra información diferente, ¿cómo podría seleccionar las celdas para que la fórmula no se pierda? Lo he probado, pero me muestra #VALUE! si hago la selección (A1;A3). Originalmente en mi hoja tengo alguna celda intercalada.

Comment: @Ruy, pues una forma sencilla y rápida es meter entre paréntesis los rangos de celdas en el primer parámetro de la llamada a la función: `=EliminarDuplicados((A1;A3);",")`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda DervCodeG, funciona perfectamente. Llevaba atascado con este problema desde hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: Me alegro @Ruy, si te ha sido útil, por favor acepta marca la respuesta como aceptada para que le pueda servir a otros usuarios. Gracias